# Business Intelligence Development Studio stuck Validating a task in a dtsx file

Tags: bids, ssis

I'm using MS Business Intelligence Development Studio.
This morning, when I open one of my dtsx files, BIDS just sits there, stuck validating one of the tasks in the particular dtsx file that I'm trying to open.

Are there things that I can do to fix this problem?

Has anyone encountered this before?

David

Answer (score 1):

I would set the `DelayValidation` property on the package and control flow tasks to **True**. So that the package doesn't validate all the tasks every time I open it. It will speed up the process of opening the packages but the package will validate any changes in the connections or schema only during run time. If you click on the task that has a connection or schema, it will still validate even if you have *DelayValidation* set to true.

Answer (score 1):

As the other responders suggest, you want to select Work Offline from the SSIS menu, then you want to open your SSIS project.

However, when you open Business Intelligence Developer Studio, there may not be an SSIS menu.  If this happens, create a throw-away SSIS project (File | New | Project | Integration Services Project).  Once the throw-away SSIS project is open, there will be an SSIS menu, from which you must select 'Work Offline'.

Next, from the Solution Explorer, right click on SSIS Packages, and select Add Existing Package.  Specify File System in the Package location control, the specify the file path to the DTSX file in the Package path control.

At this point, you can open your intended SSIS package without the excruciating delay.